# Xcode 9 auto live build ,slower Xcode ? How can I fix it?

Tags: xcode9

I just downloaded `Xcode9` And when I do coding, everytime`Xcode9` doing auto build. And my Mac slower Im waiting more..

> How can I fix it ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

> xcode > preferences > General > Uncheck 'Show live issues'

If this feature makes me slow, this is useless anymore. :)